# SwiftUI MVVM data binding decode JSON with different formats

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swiftui

My API return a JSON data with 2 possible data set formats and how do I decode it? Thank you so much in advance

result.json

```
format 1:
{
    product_name: "coffee"
    product_code: "100010"
    variant: [
        flavour: [
            {
                flavour_name: "chocolate",
                flavour_code: "C001",
            },
            {
                flavour_name: "vanilla",
                flavour_code: "C002",
            }
        ],
        size: [ { ... }, { ... } ]
    ]
}

format 2:
{
    product_name: "bread",
    product_code: "B123",
    variant: [
        portion: ["quarter", "half", "full"],
        type: ["plain", "wheat", "oat"],
    ]
}
```

MenuViewModel.swift

```
class MenuDetailViewModel: ObservableObject, MenuDetailService {
    var apiSession: APIService
    @Published var detaildata: MenuDetailData?
    
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(apiSession: APIService = APISession()) {
        self.apiSession = apiSession
    }
    
    func getMenuDetail() {
        let cancellable = self.getMenuDetail(menuCode: menuCode)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Handle error: \(error)")
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
                
            }) { (detail) in
                self.detaildata = detail.data
        }
        cancellables.insert(cancellable)
    }
    
}
```

MenuDetailService.swift

```
protocol MenuDetailService {
    var apiSession: APIService {get}
    
    func getMenuDetail(menuCode: String) -> AnyPublisher<MenuDetailAPIResponse, APIError>
}

extension MenuDetailService {
    
    func getMenuDetail(menuCode: String) -> AnyPublisher<MenuDetailAPIResponse, APIError> {
        return apiSession.request(with: APIEndpoint.menuDetail(menuCode: menuCode))
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

APIService.swift

```
protocol APIService {
    func request<T: Decodable>(with builder: RequestBuilder) -> AnyPublisher<T, APIError>
}
```

RequestBuilder.swift

```
protocol RequestBuilder {
    var urlRequest: URLRequest {get}
}
```

APISession.swift

```
struct APISession: APIService {
    func request<T>(with builder: RequestBuilder) -> AnyPublisher<T, APIError> where T: Decodable {
        
        // 1
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        
        // 2
        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: builder.urlRequest)
            // 3
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            // 4
            .mapError { _ in .unknown }
            // 5
            .flatMap { data, response -> AnyPublisher<T, APIError> in
                if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
//                    let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
//                        print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
//                    }
                    
                    if (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) {
                        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
                        // 6
                        return Just(data)
                            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: decoder)
                            .mapError {_ in .decodingError}
                            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    } else {
                    // 7
                        return Fail(error: APIError.httpError(response.statusCode))
                            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    }
                }
                return Fail(error: APIError.unknown)
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

APIEndpoint.swift

```
enum APIEndpoint {
    case menuDetail(menuCode: String)
}

extension APIEndpoint: RequestBuilder {
    var urlRequest: URLRequest {
        switch self {
        case .menuDetail(let menuCode):
            guard let url = URL(string: "API_URL/product/detail")
                else {preconditionFailure("Invalid URL format")}
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue(Constants.API_TOKEN, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            
            let body: [String: Any] = ["brand": 1, "city": "", "menu_code": menuCode, "member_phone": ""]
            let rb = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)
            request.httpBody = rb
            
            return request
        }
    }
}
```

MenuDetailAPIResponse.swift

```
struct MenuDetailAPIResponse: Codable {
    let data: MenuDetailData
}
```

MenuDetailData.swift

```
struct MenuDetailData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let productName: String
    let productCode: String
    let variant: [MenuVariant]
}

struct MenuVariant: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let flavour: [MenuFlavour]
    let size: [MenuSize]
}

struct MenuFlavour: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let flavourName: String
    let flavourCode: String
}
```

Comment: Please make your question more focused, this looks like a json decoding question that has nothing to do with MVVM or SwiftUI really. Remove all code that isn't directly relevant to what you're asking and also change the title of the question so it better reflects what you're asking about.

Comment: If your question about how to decode, why are you including all this other code with various protocols and request builders? Also, your model doesn't map to the second variant, and you say nothing about how you'd need it to map.

Comment: Try to use decoder with try catch expression and configure catch block for error "DecodingError.typeMismatch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try combine two models into one with optional variables:

```
struct MenuDetailData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let productName: String
    let productCode: String
    let variant: [MenuVariant]
}

struct MenuVariant: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let flavour: [MenuFlavour]?
    let size: [MenuSize]?
    let portion: [String]?
    let type: [String]?

}
```

and after you can check received data

```
if let _ = model.type
if let _ = model.flavour...
```

etc.

Comment: Yes thank you, feels like I tried this before and it didn't work, must have made some mistakes. It works now, thank you mate